# How to handle multi-word synonyms

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to understand the results that I'm getting in Elastic search in a couple of conditions. I have this list of synonyms defined:

```
"product insert, product inserts, qc package, qc package inserts, qc package insert, package insert => package inserts"
```

My hope was that all of the terms to the left of the arrow would be treated as the term to the right. Here is my index setting:

```
PUT /test_index
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "my_syn_filt": {
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "product insert, product inserts, package inserts, qc package, qc packages, qc insert, qc inserts, package insert, qc package insert, qc package inserts => package inserts"
            ]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "my_synonyms": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "my_syn_filt"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that when I search a couple of the terms - "product insert", I don't get the results I expect. But "product inserts" works just fine. Is there something wrong with my configuration? Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your settings and my guess is that you haven't assign `my_synonyms` analyzer to your field.

Without knowing how you define your mappings i will show you a working example:

Assuming your mapping and settings look like:

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "data": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_synonyms",  => my guess
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "my_syn_filt": {
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "product insert, product inserts, package inserts, qc package, qc packages, qc insert, qc inserts, package insert, qc package insert, qc package inserts => package inserts"
            ]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "my_synonyms": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "my_syn_filt"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Indexing some data:

```
POST my_index/_doc/1
{
  "data":"package inserts"
}
```

Query which utilities the synonyms:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
      "match": {
        "data": "product insert"
      }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
{
 "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.2876821,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "data" : "package inserts"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Without assigning the analyzer to your field you will get results only if one of the words - `package` or `inserts` are included in your search query,actually without the analyzer you executing a simple `match` query which used the default elasticsearch `standard` analyzer.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the **mapping** part so need to map it with your field and make it possible to search by **synonyms** with something like below,

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index" : {
            "analysis" : {
                "filter" : {
                    "synonym_filter" : {
                        "type" : "synonym",
                        "synonyms" : [
                            "product insert, product inserts, package inserts, qc package, qc packages, qc insert, qc inserts, package insert, qc package insert, qc package inserts => package inserts"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "analyzer" : {
                    "synonym_analyzer" : {
                        "tokenizer" : "standard",
                        "filter" : ["lowercase", "synonym_filter"] 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
            "properties": {
              "title": { 
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
              }
            }     
    }
}
```